# Adding custom headers to every request in Kotlin okHttp retrofit2 using the current code

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, retrofit2, okhttp

Im trying to add custom headers to every request by adding .addHeader() to the OkHttpClient.Builder() but im getting the following error when building:

> MicroApiClient.kt: (16, 14): Unresolved reference: addHeader

How can I correctly add custom headers to every request using the code below?

```
    package com.app.name.data
    
    import com.app.name.BuildConfig
    import com.app.name.data.source.remote.APPService
    import okhttp3.OkHttpClient
    import okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor
    import retrofit2.Retrofit
    import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory
    import retrofit2.converter.scalars.ScalarsConverterFactory
    
    object MicroApiClient {
        private val loggingInterceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor().setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY)
        private val okHttpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .addInterceptor(loggingInterceptor)
                // Attempting to add headers to every request
                .addHeader("x-api-key", BuildConfig.AWS_MICROSERVICES_API_KEY)
                .build()
        val instance: APPService by lazy {
            val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BuildConfig.AWS_MICROSERVICES_HOST)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
                    .client(okHttpClient)
                    .build()
    
            retrofit.create(APPService::class.java)
        }
    }
```

Comment: have you tried the solution below?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per **Retrofit** documentation :

> Interceptors can add, remove, or replace request headers.

Interceptor are used to manipulate outgoing request or the incoming response. In your case you have to add *API_KEY* to every request as header. That's where the interceptor can be handy. You can add header in the interceptor as below:

```
 private val okHttpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .addInterceptor(loggingInterceptor)
                // Attempting to add headers to every request
                .addInterceptor { chain ->
                     val request = chain.request().newBuilder()
                     .addHeader("x-api-key", BuildConfig.AWS_MICROSERVICES_API_KEY)
                     chain.proceed(request.build())
                }
                .build()
```

Answer (score 0):

It is simple; only use addHeader method. For Example:

```
var request= Request.Builder()
                .addHeader("Token","test")
                .addHeader("UserName","test user")
                .url(url)
                .post(jsonBody)
                .build()
```